# Select Where Child entity Id exists in an array of ints

Tags: .net, entity-framework

I have a requirement to select all Parent objects that have Child objects whos IDs are contained in an Int Array

Parent object = Broker
Child Object = Country

A Broker can have Many Countries

I want to select a list of Brokers who have Countries that match incoming array of ints

Something like:

```
if (filter.Country.Any())
                q = q.Where(b => filter.Country.ToList().Contains(b.Countries.Select(c => c.Id).ToList()));
```

in the above code 'filter' is a Model

'filter.Country' is defined as such:

```
public int[] Country { get; set; }
```

So what I am trying to say is, if filter.Country contains any IDs, only select Brokers with Countries that match the incoming Ids

The above code does not work as it errors that I am trying to match an int with an array of ints, but hopefully it explains what I am trying to achieve

Comment: Should all country id's match your broker or just one?

Comment: Just one, So any broker available in any Country

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
context.Brokers.Where(b => b.Countries.Any(c => ids.Contains(c.Id)))
```

Comment: More or less. There is no 'Ids' array in my example, but this works:
               context.Brokers.Where(broker => broker.Countries.Any(country=> filter.Country.Contains(country.Id)))